# Mouse over / hover with lots of divs in between

Tags: jquery

I'd like to show the div in grey, at the very bottom, when I mouseover/hover the div in green. The problem is that there is a lot of divs in between them. I have no idea how I would write my function with all those divs in between.

```
see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Oy7.jpg
```

edit: I need to use jquery since I'm also gonna use the attr('src','') to change an src

Comment: It's the first time I see a screenshot of code in a question... Anyways, probably you'd better provide a sample of your code through jsfiddle and try to reformulate the question with more context so people will help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe give the div to be hovered an id for clear identification ;)

Static method with css:

```
.field-name-hover-div:hover + div #techinfo {
    css-rules
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bZHFG/

Edit: Solution with jQuery:

```
var applyWhenEnter = function() {
    $('#techinfo').css({'attrName': 'value'}); // Add properties to the object for every css value you want to change.
};

var removeWhenLeave = function() {
    $('#techinfo').css({'attrName': ''}); // Add properties to the object for every css value you want to change.
};

$('.field-name-hover-div').hover(applyWhenEnter, removeWhenLeave);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r3NCx/2/

Comment: I couldn't get yours to work on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/360/ but I was able to get one to work with some slight variation. Same concept. http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/363/

Comment: As you can see in the fiddles, it is working, but you have to keep the order of the statements as the variable has to get a value prior to use it.

Answer (score 0):

try using a css hover selector:

```
.field-name-hover-div:hover #techinfo
{
  /* Add changes here */
}
```